# Discord bot doesn't message the user that I tagged

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am pretty new to node js and I have trouble making my discord bot to message the user that I tag. Here is an example of how the code should be:

User: howcool @MyFriend
Bot: @My friend is 75% cool!

Here is my unsuccessful code below:

```
    client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    let mention = message.mentions.users.first()

    if (msg.startsWith(".pfx howcool") && mention) {
        message.channel.send(`${mention} is ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1}% cool!`)
        
    } else if (message.content === ".pfx howcool"){
        message.channel.send(`You are ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1}% cool!`)
}});
```

Comment: You might get an error when you are not mentioning an user - `Cannot read property first of undefined` if its not so please tell the error

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `` (`${mention} is ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1}% cool ``
you can use: ``` (``<@{mention.id}> is ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1}% cool ```

Mention is a Discord.User Object that includes data for id, system, locale, flags, username, bot, discriminator, avator, lastmessadeID, lastmessagechannelid

To ping someone you need to use id in the following format: <@{mention.id}> which also is what discord does when you ping someone as a user.

```
    if(message.content.startsWith('.pfx howcool') && mention){
        message.channel.send(`<@${mention.id}> is ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1}% cool`)
    }
    if(message.content.startsWith('.pfx howcool') && !mention){
        message.channel.send(`You are ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1}% cool!`)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return; //Ignore the bot messages

    if(message.content.startsWith(".pfx howcool"){ //Sorting the command name
      if(message.mention.members){ //If there are mentions
          message.channel.send(`<@${message.mention.members.first().id}> is ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1}% cool`)
      }else if(!message.mention.members){ //If there no mentions.
        message.channel.send(`You are ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1}% cool!`)
    }
}
```

**Please read the comentars then you will understand the code that I wrote much better!**